# How can I set custom font in UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

How can I set custom font in UINavigationBar ? I need the tahoma font.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.title =@"My text";
}
```

[image]

Comment: The Tahoma font is owned by Microsoft. Once you've sorted out the licensing side of things let us know and we'll help you with the coding. :-)

Comment: But iphone has built-in tahoma font. I do need any licenses.

Comment: Tahoma is not one of the built-in fonts

Comment: grahamparks, i uploaded the picture

Comment: Those are a list of fonts installed on your Mac, not ones available to an iOS device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Totally possible, if a little tricky to do. Once you've found the font you need (either one of the alternatives already shipped with iOS, or a TTF file that you've got the correct licensing for), just create a UILabel with the size, formatting, font etc and then add it to the navigation items for that bar (or, if you're doing this in a view controller, set the .navigationItem.titleView of that controller to your label).

For example, I have a view controller inside a UINavigationController. To change the label in the top to a custom font, I simply do:

```
//...I have already setup a UILabel called navLabel that has the same style as a 
// default navigation bar title, but I've changed the .font property to my custom font
self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
[navLabel release];
```

Comment: for completeness you could edit the answer to also point to a list of available fonts like [this one](http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts) ;)

Answer (score 17):

This code should work. In uiviewcontroller which presents your main ui:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        int height = navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
        int width = navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;

        UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
        navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        navLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
        [navLabel release];
}
```

Note that resulting custom view has transparent background, so that you can add something more to your navigation bar with [navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view]. This may be spinner in left corner of the bar or something else.

If you use custom view, you will not be able set the title with uiviewcontroller title anymore. You need to use the way available by your custom view.

Example:

```
((UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView).text = title;
```