# Can I free use tahoma font in iPhone app development?

Tags: iphone, uifont

Can I free use tahoma font in app development?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tahoma is not one of the fonts included on the iPhone or iPad (see [here](http://www.michaelcritz.com/2010/04/02/fonts-for-ipad-iphone/) for a list). There are ways to bundle a font with your app, but you'd have to have an appropriate license to do so. As a workaround, it may be allowed to include pre-rendered graphic files with your app that use Tahoma.

(per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699905/how-can-i-set-custom-font-in-uinavigationbar): Tahoma may show up in the font picker in Interface Builder, but that's just the standard system-wide font picker, and all it indicates is that you have Tahoma installed on your Mac)

Comment: I wrote a tool for that! Display every font on the iDevice https://github.com/palmerc/iOS5Fonts

Comment: All links in this accepted answer go to spam. Has this post been corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

Well the [typography FAQ from microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/RedistributionFAQ.mspx) says that

> "You are not allowed to copy,
>   redistribute or reverse engineer the
>   font files"
>
> A number of Microsoft fonts are now
>   available to end users, ISVs and OEMs
>   under license from Ascender
>   Corporation. These include 'Verdana',
>   'Georgia', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Microsoft
>   Sans Serif', 'Nina', '**Tahoma**',
>   'Wingdings', 'Webdings' and 'Trebuchet
>   MS'.

from what i understand you are supposed to buy a license from Ascender Corp. if you want to use them in your product.

Comment: Note that it's not enough to buy the font from Ascender, you must specifically get a license that allows you to distribute the font.